# Python ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)

Tags: python, dictionary, translate

So I am learning python and redoing some old projects. This project involves taking in a dictionary and a message to be translated from the command line, and translating the message. (For example: "btw, hello how r u" would be translated to "by the way, hello how are you".

We are using a scanner supplied by the professor to read in tokens and strings. If necessary I can post it here too. Heres my error:

```
Nathans-Air-4:py1 Nathan$ python translate.py test.xlt test.msg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "translate.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "translate.py", line 13, in main
    dictionary,count = makeDictionary(commandDict)
  File "/Users/Nathan/cs150/extra/py1/support.py", line 12, in makeDictionary
    string = s.readstring()
  File "/Users/Nathan/cs150/extra/py1/scanner.py", line 105, in readstring
    return self._getString()
  File "/Users/Nathan/cs150/extra/py1/scanner.py", line 251, in _getString
    if (delimiter == chr(0x2018)):
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

Heres my main translate.py file:

```
from support import *
from scanner import *
import sys

def main():
    arguments = len(sys.argv)
    if arguments != 3:
        print'Need two arguments!\n'
        exit(1)
    commandDict = sys.argv[1]
    commandMessage = sys.argv[2]

    dictionary,count = makeDictionary(commandDict)

    message,messageCount = makeMessage(commandMessage)

    print(dictionary)
    print(message)

    i = 0
    while count < messageCount:
        translation = translate(message[i],dictionary,messageCount)
        print(translation)
        count = count + 1
        i = i +1
    main()
```

And here is my support.py file I am using...

```
from scanner import *

def makeDictionary(filename):
    fp = open(filename,"r")

    s = Scanner(filename)
    lyst = []
    token = s.readtoken()
    count = 0
    while (token != ""):
        lyst.append(token)
        string = s.readstring()
        count = count+1
        lyst.append(string)
        token = s.readtoken()
    return lyst,count

def translate(word,dictionary,count):
    i = 0
    while i != count:
        if word == dictionary[i]:
            return dictionary[i+1]
            i = i+1
        else:
            return word
            i = i+1
    return 0

def makeMessage(filename):
    fp = open(filename,"r")

    s = Scanner(filename)
    lyst2 = []
    string = s.readtoken()
    count = 0
    while (string != ""):
        lyst2.append(string)
        string = s.readtoken()
        count = count +  1
    return lyst2,count
```

Does anyone know whats going on here? I've looked through several times and i dont know why readString is throwing this error... Its probably something stupid i missed

Comment: What character, exactly, are you expecting `chr(0x2018)` to represent?

Comment: The error message clearly shows that the problem comes up in `scanner.py`. Is that the code your professor wrote? What version of Python are you using? What version of Python did your professor tell you to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`chr(0x2018)` will work if you use Python 3.

You have code that's written for Python 3 but you run it with Python 2. In Python 2 `chr` will give you a one character string in the ASCII range. This is an 8-bit string, so the maximum parameter value for `chr`is `255`. In Python 3 you'll get a unicode character and unicode code points can go up to much higher values.

Comment: Please, is there any way to get by this issue without installing Python 3?

Comment: In Python 2 you can use [`unichr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) but please think about moving on to Python 3. Python 2 has reached end-of-life already.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that the character you're converting using `chr` isn't within the range accepted (`range(256)`). The value `0x2018` in decimal is 8216.

Check out [unichr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=chr#unichr), and also see [chr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=chr#chr).

Comment: But the format of the file it is reading is abbreviation "definition" abbreviation "definition" etc... the even indexed values are always strings. Why would the limit be 256 for something like this? Maybe the scanner is wrong?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the content of your file. The limit is 255 (`range`s do not include the high endpoint) because that's how `chr` is defined. This is clear if you read the documentation.