# Receiving the error ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)

Tags: python, ascii

```
elif chosenA == 2:
print('''You have chosen to decrypt a message,''')
print("Please enter the name of the file you wish to decrypt")
a = raw_input()
with open(a + '.txt') as text:
    lar = text.read()
    print(lar)
MS = 0
print("oi drongo enter ya key")
b = raw_input()

for c in b:
    f = ord(c)
    MS = MS + f
geek = (MS / 8) - 32
#print(geek)

nlar = ''

for c  in lar:
    g = ord(c)
    if g > 126:
        g -= 94
    g -= geek
    f = unichr(g)
    print(f)
```

During the "for c in lar:" I am trying to get the characters in the file to be converted to ascii values using ord() and then if they are greater than 126 (the alphabet) remove 94 from the value then take geek(the offset factor generated from an 8 character key) away from the ascii value so it will be returned to text that was originally encrypted, if you want the full code just say and I'll provide it if it will help.

Comment: In the full traceback, it tells you what line the error occurred on. Have you tried (on the line before that) adding a print statement that prints the value you are passing into `chr`? If not, then do that, and you will see that the value you're passing to chr is not in the range 0-255. Then you can work backwards from there to find out why.

Comment: I have printed "g" before it is passed onto chr() and it is returning values now but I think my problem is that I made my program set spaces as "32" earlier on to remove them from the encryption phase but the only values that are negative are ones that are punctuation marks.

Comment: Looks like you've found the problem then :)

Comment: But please Mr. Tom, I don't have a solution :{        if c == 32:
            c = ' '

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327901/python-valueerror-chr-arg-not-in-range256)